# Django - load page fragments using Ajax/Ajah

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, include

I have a complex page where some parts of the page take more time to load. I was thinking about using AJAH approach and load fragments using jQuery after initial page is loaded. Then I realized that should be quite common problem. How about some something like {% includeajax "sometemplate.html" %}?

What this means is load "sometemplate.html" using AJAH/AJAX. Wouldn't that be cool tag? Any ideas?

I know how to implement this, it would be nice to have reusable tag like this. Do you know about some other simple way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a middleware and a template tag to do this:

```
{% delayed_block big_table %}
    Real content. It will be loaded by Javascript at document.ready event.
{% delayed_stub %}
    Stub content that is rendered immediately.
{% enddelayed_block %}
```

When the page is loaded, a piece of Javascript notices a special class and requests it from the server, makes a request with `?partial=big_table` parameter. When `big_table` is in `partial` parameters, this block renders the real content. The middleware catches the output, extracts only this block and wraps it in JSON. Then the Javascript module puts it into the right place.

The project is called [django-partial-page](https://bitbucket.org/siberiano/django-partial-page). The django part of it is an egg, and the Javascript module is in `example/media/js/partial.js`.

Comment: That's great I will have a look at it. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it point to a view instead of a template, in the style of `url`. The template tag could generate a fake `HttpRequest` that it could send to the view, and then include the content of the response in the template.

Comment: Pointing it to the view makes more sense, I agree. Why fake HttpRequest? I would prefer tag would generate JavaScript code that would fetch and include content of the view (the fragment). Maybe we mean the same just don't understand each other.

Comment: Generating JavaScript is feasible (if not necessarily straightforward), but it means that you have to do *another* round trip to the server in order to display it. Since you're *already* at the server, you may as well just get it now.

Comment: Whole point is that I want to get it asynchronously because it might take more time to get the data used to render the fragment. I don't want user to wait 2-3 seconds. I load page and and then make additional trip to get that page  fragment.

Comment: Alright. So then have the template tag add a pending request to the `onload` event's function, which you declare in the base.